# When talking about the weather, what does 'There isn't much' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It's often very cold here, but there isn't much now.

What is the last half talking about? I mean I think it's implied that it's talking about the temperature. I thought this much of implication was allowed in conversation. (The sentence above is brought up by someone studying English and it sounds like it's from a grammar quiz)

PS: I'd like to hear from AmE too. I just want to know what would be possible in casual conversation, not about grammar or logic.

PPS: I want to make sure what "~, but there isn't much **snow**" means. This is still talking about the general climate of the place, right?

By the way, the expression in my native language is closer to "It snows a lot every year," but we don't express it as "There's much snow every year."

Comment: I strongly suspect that the last word is a typo for 'snow'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That makes the sentence very clear to me too, but if the speaker is looking at a thermometer, then isn't my interpretation also possible?

Comment: Much what? We don't use words like 'much' or 'little' to talk about temperature. The second part of the sentence doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not even casually?

Comment: 'There isn't much now' would only be meaningful if something like rain or snow had been mentioned previously.

Comment: I'd like to hear from AmE too. I just want to know what would be possible in casual conversation, not about grammar or logic.

Comment: The quoted sentence doesn't make sense!  It says "there isn't much *temperature* now.  But temperature is an abstract noun, and you cant have "much temperature".  So the whole expression is incomprehensible.

Comment: @JamesK > It says "there isn't much temperature now. -- Thank you! :) What we learners want to know is often something like this: things that are not in grammar books.

Comment: to your PPS: Yes, that would be saying that in general, year to year, it's cold a lot but snow is rare.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted sentence doesn't make sense! It says "there isn't much temperature now. But temperature is an abstract noun, and you cant have "much temperature". So the whole expression is incomprehensible.

It may be a typo for "there isn't much snow".  This would be a general comment about the climate (it rarely snows)